# MySQL error 1064 creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Trying to create a table with two foreign keys and keep getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'idbed MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
idnumber MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,' at line 2
```

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE care(
idbed MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
idnumber MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(idbed, idnumber),
FOREIGN KEY(idbed) REFERENCES intensivecarebed(idbed)
FOREIGN KEY(idnumber) REFERENCES employee(idnumber));
```

the other two tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
salary FLOAT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
specialization VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL<
clinic_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(idnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE intensivecarebed(
idbed MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
clinic_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
tax_reg_number TINYINT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(idbed)
);
```

Anybody insights?

Comment: Ther is some syntax error in the following line:                                                 specialization VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL<                                                              < should be replaced by ',' in the first create                                                     After correcting this syntax error, i executed this sccript in my MySQL server it went ok...

Comment: `specialization VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL<` one `<` which must be `,`. Don't you need `idnumber MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,` also in table Employee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

- You missed `idnumber` in `Employee` table.
- You missed coma between foreign keys.
- You had `<` instead of `,`

You also have to create `care` table after creating other two tables because you are referring to these tables.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    idnumber MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    salary FLOAT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    specialization VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    clinic_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(idnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE intensivecarebed(
    idbed MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    clinic_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    tax_reg_number TINYINT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(idbed)
);

CREATE TABLE care(
    idbed MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    idnumber MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(idbed, idnumber),
    FOREIGN KEY(idbed) REFERENCES intensivecarebed(idbed),
    FOREIGN KEY(idnumber) REFERENCES employee(idnumber)
);
```

Comment: could you answer with a small explanation?